# How can I call the FailoverClusters PowerShell module when working from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

I’m trying to call a PowerShell script from C#, which is usually very straightforward, except that for some reason the commands in the FailoverClusters module can never be found when calling from C# (not in scope). Here’s what I’ve discovered:

The commands are always found when using an interactive PowerShell session:

```
PS C:\> Get-Cluster -Name DummyCluster

Name
----
DummyCluster
```

The commands are never found when using a local PowerShell session from C#:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-Cluster");
ps.AddParameter("Name", "DummyCluster");
var r = ps.Invoke();
//Exception: command not found
```

I’ve tried about 6-7 different ways to import the module, and none of them worked. Here is one of them, taken from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/374052/Import-PowerShell-modules-and-excute-CmdLets-using) tutorial on the subject:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
var ss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
var modules = new string[1]{"FailoverClusters"};
ss.ImportPSModule(modules);
var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ss);
rs.Open();
var iv = new RunspaceInvoke(rs);
var r = iv.Invoke("Get-Cluster -Name DummyCluster");
//Exception: command not found
```

Interestingly, the commands are found when using a remote PowerShell session. This is a plausible work-around for certain use cases.

```
var ci = new WSManConnectionInfo(); //localhost remote connection
var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ci);
rs.Open();
var iv = new RunspaceInvoke(rs);
var r = iv.Invoke("Get-Cluster -Name DummyCluster");
//Exception: access is denied
```

The FailoverClusters module is not visible from C#:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-Module");
ps.AddParameter("ListAvailable");
ps.AddArgument("FailoverClusters");
var results = ps.Invoke();
Console.WriteLine(results.Count.ToString()); //prints 0
```

It is, however, visible from an interactive PowerShell session:

```
PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable FailoverClusters


    Directory: C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   2.0.0.0    FailoverClusters                    {Add-ClusterCheckpoint, Add-ClusterDisk, Add-ClusterFileSe...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FailoverClusters module is only available in 64-bit PowerShell sessions. Make sure that the C# DLL you're building is a 64-bit DLL.

Comment: THANK YOU!!  That little bit of info was the tipping point, after almost 2 days of banging head against wall...